# passing around NSManagedObjects

Tags: core-data, swift2, xcode7, nsmanagedobject

I get strange errors when I am trying to pass around NSManagedObject through several functions. (all are in the same VC).

Here are the two functions in question:

```
func syncLocal(item:NSManagedObject,completionHandler:(NSManagedObject!,SyncResponse)->Void) {

    let savedValues = item.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys([
        "score",
        "progress",
        "player"])

    doUpload(savedParams) { //do a POST request using params with Alamofire
        (success) in

        if success {
            completionHandler(item,.Success)
        } else {
            completionHandler(item,.Failure)
        }        
    }    
}


func getSavedScores() {

    do {
        debugPrint("TRYING TO FETCH LOCAL SCORES")
        try frc.performFetch()

        if let results = frc.sections?[0].objects as? [NSManagedObject] {

            if results.count > 0 {

                print("TOTAL SCORE COUNT: \(results.count)")

                let incomplete = results.filter({$0.valueForKey("success") as! Bool == false })
                print("INCOMPLETE COUNT: \(incomplete.count)")

                let complete = results.filter({$0.valueForKey("success") as! Bool == true })
                print("COMPLETE COUNT: \(complete.count)")

                if incomplete.count > 0 {

                    for pendingItem in incomplete {

                        self.syncScoring(pendingItem) {
                            (returnItem,response) in

                            let footest = returnItem.valueForKey("player") //only works if stripping syncScoring blank

                            switch response { //response is an enum

                            case .Success:
                                print("SUCCESS")

                            case .Duplicate:
                                print("DUPLICATE")

                            case .Failure:
                                print("FAIL")

                            }
                        }
                    }  //sorry for this pyramid of doom
                }
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("ERROR FETCHING RESULTS")
    }  
}
```

What I am trying to achieve:
 1. Look for locally saved scores that could not submitted to the server.
 2. If there are unsubmitted scores, start the POST call to the server.
 3. If POST gets 200:ok mark item.key "success" with value "true"

For some odd reason I can not access returnItem at all in the code editor - only if I completely delete any code in syncLocal so it looks like

```
func syncLocal(item:NSManagedObject,completionHandler:(NSManagedObject!,SyncResponse)->Void) {

    completionHandler(item,.Success)

}
```

If I do that I can access .syntax properties in the returning block down in the for loop.

Weirdly if I paste the stuff back in, in syncLocal the completion block keeps being functional, the app compiles and it will be executed properly.

Is this some kind of strange XCode7 Bug? Intended NSManagedObject behaviour?

[image: line 1 was written with stripped, line 2 pasted rest call back in]

line 1 was written with stripped, line 2 pasted rest call back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is thread confinement in Core Data managed object contexts. That means that you can use a particular managed object and its context only in one and the same thread.

In your code, you seem to be using controller-wide variables, such as `item`. I am assuming the `item` is a `NSManagedObject` or subclass thereof, and that its context is just one single context you are using in your app. The FRC context must be the main thread context (a `NSManagedObjectContext` with concurrency type `NSMainThreadConcurrencyType`).

Obviously, the callback from the server request will be on a background thread. So you cannot use your managed objects.

You have two solutions. Either you create a child context, do the updates you need to do, save, and then save the main context. This is a bit more involved and you can look for numerous examples and tutorials out there to get started. This is the standard and most robust solution.

Alternatively, inside your background callback, you simply make sure the context updates occur on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   // update your managed objects & save
}
```